# Is host-to-host file transfer possible using USB Type-C?

Tags: usb, hardware, usb-drive, disk

I'm doing a warranty replacement on my Chromebook Pixel 2, and want to transfer data from one laptop to another. The Pixel 2 has two USB type-C ports. I'm running Arch Linux on the old one. I'd like to just be able to `dd` my partition data over from the old laptop to the new one.

I have a C-to-C cable and a C-to-A cable (both male-to-male). Can this be done?

Comment: if you can boot both off external media (eg: install disk) you may be able to use dd and netcat to transfer the drive image over the network (wifi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB does not do host to host, one of the devices must support client mode. this requires hardware that supports client mode, kernel with "widget support" enabled and suitable client software.